# I want my Discord bot to leave and dm the owner that it left if the server is under 30 members

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, chatbot

I am making a Discord bot in discord.js and I am trying to make it direct message the owner that it left before it leaves a server under 30 members.

Here is my code so far:

```
client.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
if (guild.memberCount <30) {
    guild.leave();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Guild#ownerId`, and `UserManager#send()`

```js
if (guild.memberCount < 30) {
  await client.users.send(guild.ownerId, "I left the server because there are less than 30 members")
  await guild.leave()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
client.on("guildCreate", async (guild) => {
    if (guild.memberCount < 30) {
        const owner = await guild.fetchOwner();
        await owner.send("I left the server.");
        await guild.leave();
    }
});
```

Explanation: if the server/guild has less than 30 members, first the bot fetches the owner of the guild with `guild.fetchOwner()`, then it sends a message to the owner, and finally the bot leaves the guild.